# CSS 3d transform to match warped rectangle

Tags: html, css, css-transforms

I am looking for way to calculate transformation of element (in my case video) to fit into a warped rectangle, for example the screen area of the image below:

[image: Imac image]

I know that combination of perspective, translation and rotation should do the trick, however, I am yet to find a method to calculate the transformation without solving a few math projection equations.